# How to make a framebox to override marginnote

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, boxes, mdframed, marginnote

I'm working on a book where I have to have `marginnote`'s throughout the whole text but I also would like to include some `tcolorbox`and `mdframed`environments which override this margin.[image]

In the image below, I would like the pink/red box to occupy also the left margin yet I'd also like to keep the image below in the margin.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Excuse me for this comment. I see that there are for the kinetic energy some errors for `frac` command. But the image is of your book?

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks for noticing! I already fixed it, it was just a slip up of me not writing the \ before compiling. Any thoughts on how to make the framed environment ignore the margin though?

Comment: But have you a fragment of your image? If the answer is no, you can see in The Legrand Orange Book https://www.latextemplates.com/templates/books/2/book_2.pdf pag.10 where there is the same style of the image. The @Ignasi 's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `add to width` and `right` or `left` dimensions to include the margin notes inside the `tcolorbox` frames.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[add to width=3cm, right=3.4cm]
\lipsum[2]\marginnote{this is a margin note}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]\marginnote{this is a margin note}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: It seems from comments that OP wanted something like just a colored box wider than regular paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    sharp corners,
    colback=red!15,
    colframe=red!80!black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    leftrule=1mm,
    add to width=\marginparwidth,
    add to width=\marginparsep,
}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[2]\marginnote{this is a margin note}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way that the first tcolorbox did not have the margin space ? While on the same page having a margin?

Comment: @JuampisSalas I don't understand t'he qüestions, could explainnit better?

Comment: Basically I'd like to change the margin for only parts of a page. I want there to be a 4cm margin in normal text (where I can put marginnotes) and 1cm margin next to the mdframed boxes.

Comment: @JuampisSalas Please take a look at edited answer. Is this what you want?